# $\mathcal Z$-Transformation in Discrete Time

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform

I want to find the inverse $\mathcal Z$-transform of this, in discrete time:
$$X(z) = \frac{1}{1+3z^{-1}+2z^{-2}}$$

Comment: homework is ok for specific questions related to an attempt to solve it. You haven’t tried

Comment: Ok, so do you want me to post a wrong solution? You don't know if I tried.

Comment: yes, post what you tried.  I gave you a hint.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework problem without any attempt to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

factor the polynomial and compute the partial fraction expansion.

Hint 2:
$$ \frac{1}{(1-az^{-1})(1-bz^{-1})}=\frac{A}{(1-az^{-1})}+\frac{B}{(1-bz^{-1})}$$

solve for $A$ and $B$ when $z=a$ and $z=b$

Comment: We use fraction expansion when the polynomial degree of the numerator is smaller than the degree of the denominator. Here we have the same degree in numerator and denominator, so I can't solve it like this.

Comment: ok , try this,  multiply the top and bottom , by $z^2$ so the bottom looks like what is familiar to you.  Now factor the denominator $(z-a)(z-b)$  where $a$ and $b$ are numbers you found.  Now divide top and bottom by $z^2$,  numerator is one.  denominator is $(1-a z^{-1})(1-bz^{-1})$. Is this looking familiiar.

Comment: see how to do the partial fraction expansion:  http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/BackGround/PartialFraction/PartialFraction.html